# Bounding box regression using overfeat based fully connected cnn

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks

i am implementing VPGNET which is an overfeat based paper for lane and road marking detection. Its a multi task network with four tasks

Grid box regression
Grid mask
Multi class
Vanishing point prediction
Task 2,3,4 are classification tasks, so they are learning and inferring okay. But grid box regression task isn't learning.

It has a constant loss. I am using linear activation function on the last layer and using Mean Absolute error L1 loss function for bounding box regression task as per paper. I am not normalising any bounding box coordinates, so their range is 0-640 (width) and 0-480 height. The training MAE loss starts off really high, 17.5 to be exact and then stays there.
When I normalise the output before training, the loss starts quite low 0.02 and keeps decreasing.